# Aquamacs error code 139

Tags: aquamacs, mozart

I'm getting a "**Process Oz Emulator exited abnormally with code 139**" whilst trying to test a program using Mozart/Aquamacs. From looking at some of the other posts it looks as though the "139" error is a general error code. Code someone point me in the right direction as what to look for or do?

I'm on a Macbook 10.7.5, I have XCode installed, I installed Mozart and Aquamacs (correctly it seems). I've tried running some simple lines of code with 'Feed Region' ex:

```
{Browse 'Hello World'}
```

but no luck, just the code error.

Thanks in advance.

I didn't know which section to post this in as (after looking at all the other posts it looks like a general error, not 'Aquamacs' specific?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are using Mozart 2, which is only supported on OS 10.8/10.9. For 10.7, use Mozart 1.4.

Now if you have installed Aquamacs3, Mozart will not be able to find Aquamacs. That's because the Aquamacs has changed the directory names a bit. To solve that problem, open up Terminal and type in the following commands:

ln -s /Applications/Aquamacs.app "/Applications/Aquamacs Emacs.app"
ln -s /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs "/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs Emacs"

This of course assumes that you have put Aquamacs in applications. If not, change directories in the commands above accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks.

In fact I tried all that a while ago, and it didn't help. In the end I just downgraded to the 1.4.0 version....which works like a treat.

Thanks for the suggestion anyhow.